Dev container file ownership (Dev container extention)
I am trying to open a dev container using the vscode extension on a linux PC. The problem is that when I open the project, I have no access to any files so, I've added this post-create.sh script:
#!/bin/sh
ls -a
chown -R vscode:vscode /workspaces/babylon-decoder-manager

Now things work in the container, but when I close the container, I have no access on bare metal files...
How can I make it so I don't need to change the ownership every time I open/close a dev container?
Here is my devcontainer.json:
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/typescript-node
{
  "name": "Babylon Decoder Manager",
  "runArgs": [
    "--name",
    "babylon-decoder-manager",
    "--network=babylon"
  ],
  // Or use a Dockerfile or Docker Compose file. More info: https://containers.dev/guide/dockerfile
  "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/rust:1-1-bullseye",
  "containerEnv": {
    "ROCKET_PROFILE": "docker"
  },
  // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
  // "features": {},
  // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
  "forwardPorts": [
    "3500:3000"
  ],
  "appPort": "3500:3000",
  "postCreateCommand": "sh .devcontainer/scripts/post-create.sh",
  "postAttachCommand": "sh .devcontainer/scripts/post-attach.sh",
  "mounts": [
    "source=${env:HOME}/.ssh,target=/home/vscode/.ssh,type=bind,consistency=cached"
  ],
  // Configure tool-specific properties.
  "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
      "settings": {
        "workbench.colorTheme": "Vim Deep Dark",
        "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
          "textMateRules": [
            {
              "scope": [
                "comment",
                "keyword",
                "variable.language"
              ],
              "settings": {
                "fontStyle": ""
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "editor.fontSize": 13,
        "editor.fontFamily": "'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', monospace, 'Droid Sans Fallback'",
        "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons"
      },
      "extensions": [
        "aaron-bond.better-comments",
        "vscodevim.vim",
        "vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons",
        "johnpapa.vscode-peacock",
        "vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons",
        "drKnoxy.vscode-rainbow-brackets",
        "HarryHopkinson.vim-theme",
        "tamasfe.even-better-toml",
        "1YiB.rust-bundle",
        "rust-lang.rust-analyzer"
      ]
    }
  },
  // Uncomment to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
  "remoteUser": "vscode"
}

NOTE: Changing the remoteUser to root is NOT an option.
